# Turing Machine to write number

Tags: turing-machines

How to construct a single-tape Turing Machine which writes the number 7 in UNARY number system, leaving the tape with a delimiter symbol followed by 7 1s?

So outout would be a tape contains #111111 and blank symbols afterward.

Answer (score 1):

The language you describe is regular (because it's finite), so this can be really straight forward.

You could simple write a `1` and advance to the next state. Create 7 states, one state for each `1`.

Consider `input\output/direction` the syntax for "if `input` is on the tape write `output` and move in `direction`"

---

[image: turingmachine]

Comment: I thought of this at solution at 1st glance actually, but I thought there is a more efficient way of achieving this. Thanks for your effort of course :)

Comment: There are small machines that produce a large number of 1's, but to find them is not as easy as it seems. Have you heard of the [Busy Beaver problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver)?

Comment: Well, you won't be more *efficient*, because you'd still have at least 7 steps. You could probably find a machine with fewer states, but that get's complicated.